# What Stack Exchange site would I go for questions of the legality of quoting reviews on other websites

Tags: support, stack-exchange, site-recommendation

I have a client who is asking me to add Yelp/Urbanspoon reviews onto his website (without using the API, just direct copy + paste), and I'm not sure about the legal cautions I should take.

Is there an existing Stack Exchange site that can help me understand the legalities of doing what my client has asked?

Comment: Nothing to fear, you are in the right place, and we actually have a tag just for what you are asking.  I removed the excess from your post and retagged it for you.

Comment: What is the purpose of his website?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. You should talk to a lawyer.

While some questions related to law and licensing are on-topic for some Stack Exchange sites, personal legal advice is not. Unless you're comfortable interpreting the relevant licenses yourself, you're better off advising your client to seek legal advice before exposing himself to liability in this regard.

Comment: Yup. Or in this case, talk to Yelp to get permission or a statement